# Cursor cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Anyone have experienced this error below:

```
The type com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I've done doing project clean but still have this error with my Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform `ctrl+shift+t com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor` and see if `Cursor` is accessible within your Eclipse. If not, make it available by adding the jar in the classpath. If yes, please check the path and make sure its showing the path from your project ONLY.